# Search git log given a commit hash

Tags: git

I have a git hash from a few month ago (lets say `xyz`) and would like to 
see all the commits on the master branch before and after this hash up to today.

I know `git checkout xyz~1` goes back 1 commit before that hash and `git log` shows all the previous commits but I don't know how to go forward?

Is the `--grep` feature of git usable in this case?

Comment: Can I assume the commit `xyz` was not on the master branch? I ask because I suspect I am missing a detail in your question. If `xyz` is on the master branch then reviewing the log of just that branch would show you before and after the commit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following picture:

```
              I  <-J
             /
... <-G  <-H
             \
              K  <-L
```

The above represent Git commits—`H` stands in for some big ugly hash ID, and so do `G` and `I` and so on.  (Note: the lines from`K` to `H` and from `I` to `H` should be pointing left-ish / backwards like the others, but I don't have good arrow characters that work on everyone's system, and I'm drawing this with text instead of graphics.)

The reason you can easily go backwards is that commit `H` *contains* the big ugly hash ID of commit `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`.  So if you're standing on `H` and you run `git log`, Git shows you `H`, then `G`, then whatever comes before `G` (probably `F`), and so on.

You want to go the other way.  But ... which way *is* that?  There are two paths forward, neither of which Git can easily find for you.  One goes to `I` and then `J`.  The other goes to `K` and then `L`.

What you *can* do is pick a later starting point—ending point?—anyway, a later commit like `L` and tell Git to go backwards until it reaches `H`.  Git *can* do that, easily, because of the embedded arrows pointing backwards from each commit.

When you have Git work backwards like that, Git will eventually come to some commit whose parent is `H`.  That's the "forward" commit *in the direction of the end-point you chose*.  It's not the *other* forward commit, of course.

The main problem here is that there can be lots of ending-points, of which only a few if any lead back to `H`:

```
...--G--H--o   <-- master
      \
       J--o--o   <-- develop
           \
            o--o   <-- feature
```

We call these ending-points *branches*, or more precisely, *branch names*.  The name points to the *tip* commit.  Every commit to the left—regardless of which line it's on—is on that branch, which means that in this graph, commit `G` is on *every* branch.  Commit `J` is on *both* `develop` *and* `feature`.

Pick a branch name that you think will, eventually, lead you back to where you stand right now.  Then ask Git to do:

```
git log --topo-order --ancestry-path HEAD..master
```

for instance, to have Git start at `master` and work backwards.  (`HEAD` is the commit you're standing on right now, in this map of commits and their connections.  It's the big red "you are here" dot, and it *automatically moves with you* as you move about.)

The *last* commit that comes out of this will be one just after your current commit, *if* your current commit is reachable *from* the tip of `master`.  If not, the last commit that comes out of this is some commit reachable from `master` that's not on the same branch(es) that contain `HEAD`.  For instance, `git log --ancestry-path HEAD..feature` will list commits starting from the one `feature` points to, and working backwards until it reaches `J`.  From `J`, `git log` will step back to `G`.  That's not `HEAD`/`H` but it is *reachable from* `H`, so that's where `git log` will stop.  That's not a commit after `H` though.

What this means is that if you don't know for sure which branch(es) contain `H`, you won't know where to start.  So use:

```
git branch --contains HEAD
```

to get a list of branch names that, when Git starts at them and works backwards, those branches do contain commit `H` / `HEAD`.  You can then use the `--ancestry-path` trick to go "forwards" in that direction (you're still really going backwards, you're just stopping *just before* you get all the way to `H`).

If you hit a fork in the road, you'll [take it](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/07/25/fork-road/).  You'll take it *in the direction of* the ending-point you supplied.  Note that in a few cases, that could skip some commits:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--o--H      M--N   <-- branch
         \    /
          K--L
```

Moving "forward" from `H` to `N`, you'll either go I-J-M-N, or K-L-M-N.  Either way you may forget to visit the two you skipped.  So be careful with this.

#### Using `git rev-list`

Often, you don't really want to look through the entire `git log` output here.  There's a few short-cuts, but remember if/when you're using them that you could lose out on internal branch-and-merge structures like the ring drawn just above.  Anyway, `git rev-list` does the same thing as `git log` except that it just prints the hash IDs.  Using `--topo-order --reverse | head -1`, you can have it print the list backwards and then drop all but the first; or use it without `--reverse` and `| tail -1` for the same effect.  You can also omit the name `HEAD`.  So:

```
git checkout $(git rev-list --ancestry-path --topo-order ..branch | tail -1)
```

will move your detached HEAD one step in the direction towards `branch`, if there is such a step.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a one-shot answer because depends on what your tree looks like, where *xyz* is, and how commits are made or merged to *master*. This answer assumes you are only concerned with commits from *xyz* leading up to *master*.

Say we have this tree:

```
*   f10abeb (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'
|\  
| *   3a7ed63 Merge branch 'feature/A' into 'develop'
| |\  
| * | f3972b9 Update in develop 1
| | * f695720 Update in feature/A
| * | 20323a1 Update in develop 2 
| * | 3e81e7a Update in develop 3 
| * | 1e76a6c Update in develop 4
| * | d3bf88f Update in develop 5
| | * 205fc0e Update in feature/A
```

Say you only want to get the logs between 2 commits before `20323a1`(`xyz`) and your local copy of `master` (which I assume you mean by "*up to today*"). You don't care about the "inner" commits in `feature/A` but you do want to see when it was merged. (I'm assuming quite a lot here).

First, you need to checkout 2 commits before `20323a1`:

```
git checkout 20323a1~2
```

That would bring you to `1e76a6c`.
Then you can do:

```
git log --ancestry-path @^..master
```

That would give you logs for:
(I removed some info like date and time, etc.)

```
commit f10abebbfa9bce8074e9a4854af4fc1a000b2f6a
Merge: 6011c88 3a7ed63

    Merge branch 'develop' into 'master'

commit 3a7ed6334d492ebb7960c97c1c59c88d40c28108
Merge: f3972b9 f695720

    Merge branch 'feature/A' into 'develop'

commit f3972b9ca16ff27914120de12105b8203a2682fa

    Update in develop 1

commit 20323a1fc4c636b7e12650659ca049c2a1c497c4

    Update in develop 2 

commit 3e81e7a1624e6914dc152ca315c727e15ebf3300

    Update in develop 3

commit 1e76a6cb326ffce64ff22480a71b49de4dbdff73

    Update in develop 4
```

The [`--ancestry-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-path) option will "*only display commits that exist directly on the ancestry chain between the commit1 and commit2*" (in this example, the current commit and master).

The [`r1..r2`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation) is a dotted-range notation meaning commits "*commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1*". Then we specify `r1` to be the current commit (`@`) and `r2` to be `master`.

Answer (score 0):

1. to view the commits "up to xyz", simply use :

   ```
   git log xyz
   ```
2. to view the commits "in master, which occured after `xyz`", you can use :

   ```
   git log xyz..master
   ```

technically, the second command will exlcude `xyz` from the list, depending on your precise needs you may use `xyz~1` instead of `xyz` :

```
git log xyz~1..master
```

---

`git log` also has a ton of options to format its output.

One useful set of options to view a big set of commits is :

```
git log --oneline --graph xyz
git log --oneline --graph xyz..master
```